# Caching data which is frequently updated

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5.3

I am building an app with Laravel and the app is taking a lot of data from the database and I want to use the `Caching System` of Laravel to prevent users from always going to the database to fetch the needed data.

For this example, let's take 2 users using the app: User1 and User2

When User1 and User2 start using the app at the same time and run the method `show` in the code below. Also, the method takes the posts in the database and add it to the cache.

```
class PostController extends Controller
{

public function store(Request $request) {
    $post = Post::find(1);
    $post->name = $request['name'];
    $post->save();

    $post = Cache::put('post', $post, 60);
    return view('index', compact('post'));
}

public function show() {
    $post = Post::all();

    if(Cache::has('post')){
        $post = Cache::get('post');
    }else{
        $post = Cache::put('post', $post, 60);
    }
    return view('index', compact('post'));
}
}
```

Some minutes later, User1 run the method `store` of the code above to add a new post to the database and update his cache.
At this time  User2 is still having the same cache, he has been having since the beginning.

So my question is that, is there any way to update the cache of User2 anytime User1 makes an update ?

Comment: Are they always suppose to see the same list of posts, or are the post list individual, per user?

Comment: They are always seeing the same list of posts

Comment: What cache driver are you using? It sounds like you're using Sessions, which are individual, not global. Otherwise, just refresh the cache when a user adds a post. Next time a user updates the page, they will get the new cache.

Comment: I am using the default driver which is the ``file`` driver

Comment: Then I don't see how they can have different caches? If user1 adds a new post and sees it in his list, user2 should also see the same list when he reloads his page.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The problem has been solved.